# JSP generated random code length is not standard

Tags: java

May i know why the generated code length sometime is 9 sometime is 10 ? how can i make it standard for all?

```
public String testing() throws Exception
{ 
     String total = "";
     for(int k =0 ; k < 10 ;k++)
     {
       String chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
       String ret = "";
        int length = chars.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
            ret += chars.split("")[ (int) (Math.random() * (length - 1)) ];
        }
        total = ret;
}
 return total;
}
```

Result

```
('0QU7F73D5T')
('XQ7YZK2QV') //different length 9
('XP0KBN4IEX')
('ZIM74X1J7Q')
('570QR4A4L2')
('YTAL1IOQ37')
('TIF1UOJVT') //different length 9
('7T2PXELI2A')
('T3N0PDDHSB')
```

Comment: no error found so far. hmm

Comment: I tried your code 100 times and I got 10 character `String` every time.

Comment: I feel that there is something wrong with the method calling this method `testing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is because of splitting the `chars` string using `""` at

```
chars.split("")[ (int) (Math.random() * (length - 1)) ]
```

so instead of splitting, use

```
chars.charAt((int) (Math.random() * (length - 1)))
```

Because when split using `""` the array has been filled with `empty string` in the `0th` index

Comment: hi @ksap ,but ...may i know will it generate duplicate result ? if i apply `chars.charAt((int)`

Comment: @user3835327 no, it's same as your previous split case. in previous case you'r trying to access the characters by splitting but java has inbuilt method `charAt()` to achieve this.